# MySQL automatic date generation

Tags: mysql

Firstly let me say I'm new to and just getting my head around MySQL and finding date manipulation has its challenges. It seems to me it should be possible to have three columns:

column A contains date member joined 2020-01-12 for example, mapped from a form.

column B contains the length of membership in years 1 or 5, currently entered manually

Then calculate expiry 'date A'+ 'integer B' Year inserted in column C on member creation or update

It's OK to do manually but I feel it should be something automatic. 
If anyone can give me a start or point to a tutorial that might help I'd be grateful.

Comment: You wouldn't generally store a column which can be derived. But if you must then have a look at triggers and generated columns. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: Triggers are out I'm afraid, the host for the database I'm working with, in this case Siteground doesn't grant sufficient admin rights. I'll read the link though...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySql you can use DATE_ADD() funciton:

```
SELECT columnA, columnB, DATE_ADD(columnA, INTERVAL columnB YEAR) AS EXPIRY;
```

Use this [web page](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_add.asp) as reference.

Comment: Yes that works, had to modify slightly for Workbench to  `SELECT `joined`,`duration`, 
DATE_ADD(`joined`, INTERVAL `duration` YEAR) as Expiry
FROM `rsf96104_rsf_members`.`members`;`

Answer (score 0):

You could define triggers `BEFORE INSERT` and/or `BEFORE UPDATE` which will do the job for you:

`BEFORE INSERT` trigger:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS before_insert;
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER before_insert 
    BEFORE INSERT ON `my_table` 
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        SET NEW.`valid` = DATE_ADD(NEW.`date`, INTERVAL NEW.`membership` YEAR);
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

`BEFORE UPDATE` trigger:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS before_update;
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER before_update 
    BEFORE UPDATE ON `my_table` 
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        SET NEW.`valid` = DATE_ADD(NEW.`date`, INTERVAL NEW.`membership` YEAR);
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

It is quite enough to insert both `date` and `membership` values during insert (obviously) or to update `membership` value on already inserted record(s).

Your `Column C` is the `valid` column in both queries.